# Creating Sliders

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, slider

I'm using someone elses code for my slider.

His code looks like this

```
UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
int number = [slider value];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", number];
label.text = string;
```

It shows the slider value, from 0 - 100.

It makes perfect sense, except that I'm confused with the first line of code which is the part after  =  , the (UISlider *)sender portion.

```
UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
```

If I understand correctly, he points the UISlider to the sender and stores it into the slider instance.

I guess my question is, what happened here? Was the UISlider *slider instance allocated.. what is going on exactly behind the scenes here and can this be done with other classes too?

Thank you to anyone that bothers with replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know the sender(in this case) is responsible for the event as it invokes the event most likely an `IBAction`. Generally the sender is an untyped object which can represent any type of object. In this case the programmer is certain that its going to be invoked by a `UISlider` object. So the type-casting is done to get an object of type `UISlider`. This for example can also be done for a `UIButton` where this line can be replaced by `UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;`

Comment: Thank's I think that answers it.

Comment: Yeah that would work, except that the value property would give me an error because button doesn't contain said property. But I get what you're saying, I just tried it out . Thank you again.

Comment: Obviously that wouldn't work for this code but if you go with that you can get all the properties and instance methods for a UIButton.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand code above happens when the event occurs with some object of UISlider and accordingly this code is in the 'callback' method. Then at this moment the object is already exists, you don't need to allocate memory for it anymore (it's that object, which called this method in fact); and all this guy is doing is casting the 'sender' parameter (which is standard for any callback (IBAction?) method) to UISlider type, being assured that he actually works with an object of this class. In this way he says to the compiler: "Look, I know that this is an object of UISlider. Please, let me work with it in a standard for sliders way".

Correct me please, guys, if I'm wrong somewhere.